# Foreach loop inside while loop returns only one result

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

as the title says, the foreach loop which is inside a while loop returns only the last array.

**Current Output:**
amethyst04, rainbow07, starfish14, +3 gold

**Desired Output:**
amethyst04, rainbow07, starfish14, +2 vial, +1 candy, +3 gold

So the code below only returns the gold array from the currency array.

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show1) ) {
   // Example of $row['log_rewards'] output from the database log_rewards column:
   $row['log_rewards'] = "amethyst04, rainbow07, starfish14, vial, vial, candy, gold, gold, gold";

   // List of available currencies
   $currencyArr = "vial, candy, gold";

   $rewards = explode(', ', $row['log_rewards']);
   $curName = explode(', ', $currencyArr);

   // Declare empty strings
   $txtString = ''; 
   $curString = ''; 

   // Display cards for each reward if NOT a currency
   foreach( $rewards as $r ) {
      if( !in_array($r, $currencyNames) ) {
         $txtString .= $r.', ';
      }
   }

   // Get count of how many of each reward is present
   $values = array_count_values($rewards);

   // Display currencies that are in rewards and quantity only if exists in rewards
   // This foreach loop only shows the last currency from the $rewards array
   foreach( $curName as $cn ) {
      if( array_key_exists($cn, $values) ) {
         $curString .= ', +'.$values[$cn].' '.$cn;
      }
   }

   // Display text of rewarded cards
   $txtString = substr_replace($txtString,"",-2);

   // Print out both cards and currencies
   echo '<b>'.$row['log_title'].':</b> '.$txtString.' '.$curString;
}
```

I'm not sure if this should be explained any further as I've already mentioned the current and desired output and the problem. ^^; Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( !in_array($r, $currencyNames) ) {
```

Because there is no variable named $currencyNames. Shouldn't it be $curName?

Comment: Hi! I changed the `$currencyNames` to `$curName` and it did show the other currencies! OMG. Wanna slap myself so hard I'll see my brains. Hahah